# 小規模プロジェクトのおすすめのフレームワーク

Tags: framework

小規模プロジェクトのおすすめのフレームワーク
教えてください。
予約フォームから決済等の機能(Stripe APIなどを使用)を盛り込んだWebアプリケーションの開発を
考えています。
学習コストと工数が少ないものが理想です。
開発経験としては、
React  Velocity Thymleaf
Spring Struts Laravel 
です。おすすめありますか？

Comment: 参考にしてみてください　https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1512/

Comment: 今の質問の「学習コストと工数が少ないものが理想」とするなら、開発経験のあるフレームワークから選ぶのが一番です。